# Read Write text file using HTML code in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, html, titanium, titanium-mobile, html5-apps

I am creating HTML5 type of application in Titanium Appcelerator. I have written code in order to creates text file using using titanium code which executes properly and create text file at `/Users/demoUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FE1CF0AC-D5BD-4FAB-9615-C58D80B5A9C6/data/Containers/Data/Application/40686DB0-BFB0-4D01-98BB-9E5758C4976D/Documents/file.txt`

Now I am having a html file i.e index.html which I am loading in titanium webview within same application. Now I want to access content of `file.txt` in a function created in .html file.

Anyone who has worked on anything like this before ? Or any help or suggestion regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file either from resources directory or application directory and render it in html page like below.

```
 var readContents;
```

`var readFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'data.txt');`

`if (readFile.exists()) {
     readContents = readFile.read();
     Ti.API.info('File Exists');

}`

`var docString = readContents.toString();
Ti.API.info('Contents = ' + docString);`

`var text_in_html = "<html><body><pre>" + docString + "</pre></body></html>";`

`// Create our Webview
var myWV = Ti.UI.createWebView({
        html:text_in_html,
        title:'Title goes here',
        left:0,
        right:0,
        top:0, 
        bottom:0, 
        loading: true

    });`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input arun. But what I want is that i want to read content of file located in applicationDataDirectory from html file itself. i.e I want to create function in index.html itself which directly read content from applicationDataDirectory.